# vuforia cloud is not working

Tags: ios, json, augmented-reality, vuforia

I created database name as book, and created target name as android & turnkey. After that i upload image & metadata for android. The android metadata is book.txt file contain samplebook1.json. Also the turnkey book_1.txt file contain samplebook2.json text.

In xcode:

```
static const char* const kAccessKey = "mine key";

static const char* const kSecretKey = " mine key";
```

BooksManager.m:

```
#define BOOKSJSONURL @"https://server.net/projects/AR/Vuforia/Cloud_Reco
```

samplebook1.json:

Here i changed targetid with my targetId.

```
{"title":"Cloud Recognition in Vuforia","author":"Karina Borland","average rating":"4","# of ratings":"41","list price":"43.99","your price":"43.15","targetid":"ebd4e5049bc34c60b0d944062721a97f","thumburl":"https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/thumbs/01_thumbnail.png","bookurl":"https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/book1.php"}
```

But it's not working. Where i did mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the iOS SDK, but this part seems pretty similar. I think that your problem come from the last part of your samplebook1.json.

```
{"title":"Cloud Recognition in Vuforia","author":"Karina Borland","average rating":"4","# of ratings":"41","list price":"43.99","your price":"43.15","targetid":"ebd4e5049bc34c60b0d944062721a97f","thumburl":"https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/thumbs/01_thumbnail.png","bookurl":"https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/book1.php"}
```

The field "bookurl" permit to recovered some informations about the book. All those informations are informed at this url.

You have to use your own URL.

Hope it was helpful !